# iOS Determine button that was programmatically created

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I have made a horizontal scroll view with images and buttons in it using a for loop, what i want to do now is when a button is pressed, open the image it corresponds to full screen. The issue im having is determining which button has been pushed. I am using :

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then :

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {}
```

What can i do to fix this? Thanks

Comment: for anyone who may want this later: `[button setTag: i]` and inside the buttonPressed Method `x = sender.tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which button has been pushed

Create a `property` to store a `tag`. In the `buttonPressed` method set the property to `sender.tag`

Now you can know which was the button who got pressed last.

Answer (score 0):

The `sender` is the button that the user has tapped, so when you create the buttons you could use the `tag` property and set it to an index of an array where you hold your images. But this could be a bit unstable if you change the order or amount of images or buttons for example so be prepared to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do so is to keep references of your button (with a property, an attribute in your class) and test if it is the good one in your buttonPressed method

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
  if (sender == self.myButton) {
    // DO YOUR WORK HERE
  }
}
```

you can also create a method for this and only this one button

by the way it is better to say

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
```

you then can set the target of your button in the interface builder interface

Answer (score 0):

set tag for each button in the for loop `but.tag=i;`

> -(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
>
> if (sender.tag==1){
>
> //display image 1
>
> }
>
> else if ....
>
> }